# Find data from different year for missing sections

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table for different road sections with traffic data:

```
Route   BeginningMilePost EndMilePost  TrafficVolume   Year
1              0.5           1.5            300        2017
1              1.5           3.5            400        2017
1              3.5           4.0            200        2017
1              1.0           1.5            200        2019
1              1.5           3.5            700        2019
1              3.5           3.7            500        2019
2              3.0           4.7            250        2017
2              2.5           3.5            300        2019
2              3.5           4.0            300        2019
2              4.0           4.7            400        2019
```

As you can see from the data for Milepost 0.5 - 1.0 there is no data for 2019, So we would assume that Traffic volume for 2019 is same as 2017 and that is the same for section 3.7 - 4.0 for year 2019.

I want to create a SQL Query that creates the output from the above data as follows:

```
Route   BeginningMilePost EndMilePost  TrafficVolume   Year
1           0.5             1.0           300           2019
1           1.0             1.5           200           2019
1           1.5             3.5           700           2019
1           3.5             3.7           500           2019
1           3.7             4.0           200           2019
2           2.5             3.5           300           2019
2           3.5             4.0           300           2019
2           4.0             4.7           400           2019
```

Basically the idea is to get the latest data but if there is a piece of section that was not covered in the latest year, get the data for that section from the earliest year.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the previous year, then I'm thinking `union all`:

```
select Route, BeginningMilePost, EndMilePost, TrafficVolume, Year
from mytable
where year = 2019
union all
select Route, BeginningMilePost, EndMilePost, TrafficVolume, 2019
from mytable t
where year = 2017 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from mytable t2
                  where t2.route = t.route and
                        t2.BeginningMilePost = t.BeginningMilePost and
                        t2.year = 2019
                 );
```

This explicitly hardcodes the years as 2017 and 2019, because that is what the question asks for.  If you just want the most recent previous year, then you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

My try :) Create atomic sections which may appear in the output. It is my query `sections`, I used unpivot, but you can do it in several ways.

Now we can join data, ranking newest best and take only them (`where rnk = 1`). One problem left: continuous periods with same traffic, year. If you want to merge them you can use [tabibitosian](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915680) method.

```
with sections as (
    select rt, val bmp, lead(val) over (partition by rt order by val) emp
      from (
        select distinct rt, val
          from (select route rt, beginningmilepost bmp, endmilepost emp from routes r)
          unpivot (val for col in (bmp, emp))))
select rt, min(bmp) bmp, max(emp) emp, vol, year
  from (
    select rt, bmp, emp, vol, year, 
           row_number() over (partition by rt order by bmp) 
         - row_number() over (partition by rt, vol, year order by bmp) grp
      from (
        select s.*, trafficvolume vol, year, 
               rank() over (partition by rt, bmp, emp order by year desc) rnk
          from (select * from sections where emp is not null) s
          join routes r on rt = route and bmp < endmilepost and r.beginningmilepost < emp )
      where rnk = 1)
  group by rt, vol, year
  order by rt, bmp
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=98813db3561b6eea19f59cd2458ab7d9)</sup>**